# MATLAB Cycle through vector values sequentially in a large for Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I have a small vector that has values that need to be calculated in sequence while a large for loop executes. Each time the for loop executes, it sequentially moves from vector index 1 to end then reset until the for loop executes completely.

For example, if the vector is [4 2 1] and the for loop executes *n* times, the index value will be 4,2,1,4,2,1,4,2,1... etc.

I was wondering if there was a way to optimize or shrink some code I developed or even if there was another way to accomplish the task, simpler or not.

Here's my code:

```
cookie_jar = [prt/4 prt/2 prt];
...
for k = 1:reps;


    if k <= length(cookie_jar);
        cookie = cookie_jar(k);
    elseif rem(k,length(cookie_jar)) == 0
        cookie = cookie_jar(end);
    else 
        cookie = cookie_jar(rem(k,length(cookie_jar))); 
    end

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you negatively vote this question down, please indicate why, so the asker may know what types of questions to avoid asking in the future. Better feedback gets you better questions.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your description is overcomplicated and contains many irrelevant details. Consider this problem question: "I have a small vector that has values that need to be calculated in sequence while a large for loop executes. Each time the for loop executes, it will sequentially move from vector index 1 to end then reset until the for loop executes completely. For the input vector `[1,3,7]` the loop should use the values 1,3,7,1,3,7...". This would be a much shorter question which contains all the relevant information.

Comment: Excellent points and great comment. I implemented your recommended changes. Thank you for the constructive critique!

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix the third case to match indexing which starts with 1, then the first two cases are no longer required:

```
for k = 1:reps
   cookie=cookie_jar(rem(k-1,length(cookie_jar))+1)
   %...
end
```

Comment: This certainly looks like an optimization to me. Would there be any other way to do it? Curiosity is the main influence now.

Comment: @endowdly: You could vectorize this operation, but as long as the rest of the loop is not vectorized there is no advantage: `allcookies=cookie_jar(rem([1:reps]-1,length(cookie_jar))+1)`